# Azure: How to setup multi factor authentication policy in Azure using Terraform?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to enable multi factor authentication policy in Azure using Terraform.

I followed the article -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/howto-identity-protection-configure-mfa-policy

However not sure how this can be achieved using Terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, is not possible using the traditional providers. You could use Azure AD Provider and configure MFA using Azure AD Conditional Access Policies: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/conditional_access_policy

Comment: Are you saying conditional access policy will enable MFA? Is it not that we have to enable MFA beforehand enabling conditional access policy?

Comment: By configuring the conditional access policy, you will request that you use the MFA when logging in. If they do not have it configured, they will have to configure it

Comment: Under what circumstances user's will get locked? especially the Admin accounts? so that I will be careful enough to not lock the Admin accounts

Comment: Remember you must have an "emergency access" account and that account need to be in the section of "excluded users" of that rule